# CSS width transition using background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image, transition

I've set up a website using a background-color, to expand the full width of the screen. This worked fine as a placeholder, but my original intent was to use a background image to slide in. I've looked up how to do this, and that it isn't supported by FireFox. This was >4 years ago and I can't find any new sources on this site or any other that this may have changed (4 years is a long time!). Is there an existing, supported method to do this now?

Here's the original question for reference.
[CSS3 background image transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Thanks for answering!

Comment: You can transition `background-position` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fengelz/yPnuN/). Please include your code, show us what you're trying to do, what you've done, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks for responding! But my question isn't about code! I'm aware of how my code works and have no issue with it. This is a question of best practice because the only information I could find was out-dated. I'm not stuck, I want to know what is usually done. Links to documentation would be very useful.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for showdev, thanks.

Comment: Check out the "Animation Type" for the various shorthand properties of [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), listed under "[Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Specifications)". Many are listed as "discrete", meaning that they are [not interpolated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510663/what-are-discrete-animations).

Comment: Thanks again. Dunno why I'm getting downvotes as there aren't any current questions on this I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Showdev in comments. He uses [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to solve the issue.

Comment: It is a good thing to inform that the answer has been found. But perhaps you want to share what you did - so give the real answer - or delete this actually not-an-answer and make it as an comment to your question?

Comment: I didn't do anything, unfortunately. As I elaborate in the comments, this is not a question about ANY code I am writing. **I asked a theory question about best current practice**. My question was answered and I learned about a method that I didn't know existed. I didn't do anything beyond look at the link he sent. I will edit my answer to include a link to his answer, however.